# Random tag in the post

Tags: tags

Each post has 5 tags. But I want to display only 1 tag and every time it must be a random tag.

Can you please tell me how I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

Someone already asked this question and can be found here:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17321603/how-to-display-a-list-of-random-tags-in-wordpress/22323541]Duplicate issue is resolved[1]

Comment: It's a list of all tags (tag cloud), but I need to display 1 random pot tag in the post.

Comment: function jr_get_tags_but_exclude() {
    
        $alltags = get_tags( $args );
        shuffle($alltags);
        $count=0;
        if ($alltags) {
            foreach($alltags as $tag) {
                $count++;
                echo '<a href="'.get_tag_link($tag->term_id).'">'.$tag->name.'</a>';
        if( $count >0 ) break;
        }
    }
}